# Convert datetime format from tuple

Tags: python

I have the data in the form of tuple, which is the data from the database table (I use fetchall() function in python language, which returns tuple data type).
In one set of tiple it consists of id, datetime, and name
((id, datetime, name), (id, datetime, name), (id, datetime, name), ...)

The problem is the datetime data is not in my preferable format when displaying on html webpage.
Is there any method to convert the datetime format?

```
{% for list in timelineList %}
<tr>
    <td id="datetime">
        {{ list.1 }}    <!-- datetime display here -->
    </td>
    <td>
    {% if list.2 != None %}
        {{ list.2 }}    <!-- name of the known users -->
    {% else %}
        Unknown User
    {% endif %}  
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried using getElementById but it only gets the first date of the table (maybe when do jinja looping, each date table has the same id)

**datetime tuple:** datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss)

**datetime when display on html:** YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

**preferred format:** DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss (ex. 14/11/2022 19:30:34)

Comment: Have a look at the function `datetime.strftime()`.

Comment: strftime() works. thank you!

But I still have a problem transforming the converted date list back to tuple after I change it to list to convert the date format.

I solved that problem by making it to the array list instead (hope it works without any problem)